# error when submitting machine learning project

Tags: machine-learning, pandas

I am trying to make a submission of a machine learning classification problem. I have a test dataset where to try my model. To submit I have to build a csv file. The prblem is that when I go building this csv file by doing:

```
sub = pd.DataFrame({'instructions': test['instructions'],'compiler':new_pred_class}).to_csv('sub.csv')
sub.head()
```

I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-f223adaf5068> in <module>
  1 sub = pd.DataFrame({'instructions': test['instructions'],'compiler':new_pred_class}).to_csv('sub.csv')
----> 2 sub.head()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Can somebody please help me? Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is None.

So your first line assigns `sub = None`:

```py
sub = pd.DataFrame({'instructions': test['instructions'],'compiler':new_pred_class}).to_csv('sub.csv')
```

This is probably what you wanted:

```py
sub = pd.DataFrame({'instructions': test['instructions'],'compiler':new_pred_class})
sub.to_csv('sub.csv')
sub.head()
```